# How to include external javascript and css files in .ftl file

Tags: templates, freemarker, jive

I want to include certain js and css files from a server in the .ftl file.

I tried by giving  `<@resource.javascript file="http://servername...">` and `<#include "http://servername...">` but none worked.

Answer (score 2):

place the the stylesheet in the directory and use the `<#include "/{path to style sheet}/Styles.css">`

and make sure your style sheet is inside the styles element:

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
```

### Example using the previous approach:

---

**Test Template**

```
<html>
<head>
<#include "css/test.css">
</head>
<body>
bla bla bla
</body>
</html>
```

**Test CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background-color:#C5C5C0;}
*{font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `@resource` is (it's something framework specific there), but `#include` is normally used for including local files, not a remote URL-s. FreeMarker runs on the server, so local path here means a path on the server. (It's easy to extend FreeMarker to support remote includes, but I guess you don't really want that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you ussing Struts 2 you can include css files at this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<@s.url value='path to your css file'/>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```